# What does "!" operator denotes if it's used before an array index?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, vector, operators

I'm a beginner on competetive programming. I was stuck in a problem so I viewed
a persons code I follow.

```
    I didn't understand this following part particularly:


    int i,n,a[1005]={},b;
    vector<int>v;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>b;
        if(!a[b])v.push_back(b);
        a[b]=i+1;
    }


    here,  what does the condition "if(!a[b])" denote? I could not find it on google. 
    Please help me. Thank you
```

Comment: It denotes "not".  The `!` operator is applied to the value produced by `a[b]`.   The `!` operator will be described in any tutorial that covers the standard C++ operators.   (I am assuming that the `cin>>n` clue means that this is C++ code.)

Answer (score 0):

The `!` denotes the `not` operator. So, this is how you check the opposite of a variable's value. This is checking whether or not the array `a` at element `b` exists. If it doesn't exist, hence the `!a[b]`, then you push `b` into vector `v` and update `a[b]`. Otherwise, do nothing and just update `a[b]`.